# Spark Structured streaming: multiple sinks

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

1. We are consuming from  Kafka using  structured streaming and  writing the processed data set to s3.

   We also want to write the processed data to Kafka moving forward, is it possible to do it from the same streaming query ? (spark  version 2.1.1)
2. In the logs, I see the streaming  query progress output and I have a sample duration JSON from the log, can some one please provide more clarity on what  the difference is between `addBatch` and `getBatch`?
3. TriggerExecution - is it the time take  to both process the fetched data and writing to the sink?

   ```
   "durationMs" : {
       "addBatch" : 2263426,
       "getBatch" : 12,
       "getOffset" : 273,
      "queryPlanning" : 13,
       "triggerExecution" : 2264288,
       "walCommit" : 552
   },
   ```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Yes.

   In Spark 2.1.1, you can use `writeStream.foreach` to write your data into Kafka. There is an example in this blog: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/04/real-time-end-to-end-integration-with-apache-kafka-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html

   Or you can use Spark 2.2.0 which adds Kafka sink to support writing to Kafka officially.
2. `getBatch` measures how long to create a DataFrame from source. This is usually pretty fast. `addBatch` measures how long to run the DataFrame in a sink.
3. `triggerExecution` measures how long to run a trigger execution, is usually almost the same as `getOffset` + `getBatch` + `addBatch`.

Comment: thanks for the response, can you please clarify the following - when  writing a Dataset created from a source topic to both S3 and KAFKA    check pointing has to be specified separately for each of those sinks , so is it fair to expect that the data will be read twice from the  source topic even when using the same DataSet created from that source to write to these 2 diff sinks ?

Comment: If you have two sinks, it means you have two queries. Each query has its own Kafka consumer and fetches data from Kafka independently.

Comment: @zsxwing if two spark consumers are part of same consumer group how can they read same message from Kafka twice?

Comment: `is usually almost the same as getOffset + getBatch + addBatch`: I think this is not true for most of the cases. Most of the applications that I developed `triggerExecution` is in the magnitude of minute but the others either ms or second.

Comment: @RockSolid each writeStream creates new stream, they run independently and offsets are picked from their own checkpoint location. Different group id is created for each steam, it is as if you are running different read + write stream.